# How do I make Fn+f2/f3 change the brightness on my HP dv7-6135dx?

Tags: shortcut-keys, hp, brightness, backlight

The problem described below riddled me for quite a while and couldn't find a straight forward answer anywhere online. I have found a solution and I would like to use this post as a documentation record.

**Issue**
When I press the key combinations <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> the popup indicating the the key combination was pressed shows up and the bar fills/empties correspondingly.  However, the brightness of the screen remains the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This question was solved by the OP:**

**Solution**
The working solution was found in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/863156).  It reads as follows:

> WORKAROUND: Changing /etc/default/grub from:
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
>
> to:
>
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
>
> save, sudo update-grub then restarting allowed brightness applet or keyboard Fn and Right or Left to change brightness.

Note that I did come across posts from people with a similar issue.  Some resolved, some unresolved, but most of the posts were for different model laptops.  Your mileage may vary.

**Hardware/Software Configuration**

- Using 64-bit Ubuntu 11.10 with kernel version 3.0.0-12-generic, GNOME 3 shell (not Unity)
- Hardware: HP dv7-6135dx Laptop, Intel Core-i5-2410, Mobile Intel HD Graphics/RADEON HD 6490M