# Ubuntu 15.10(wily) Brightness control not working

Tags: shortcut-keys, brightness

The brightness buttons and the brightness control in system settings in Ubuntu 15.10 have suddenly stopped working. They were working fine at first(after I upgraded from 15.04). I have no `Xorg.conf` file but I believe that file is no longer required.

Note that `xbacklight -dec 10` (Xbacklight package installed) command works and I am able to reduce brightness through the command, however the Brightness buttons(F11,F12) fail to respond.Also I am unable to adjust brightness through system settings(gnome-control-center). I have tried making changes to /etc/default/grub but they have no effect.

Command: `cd /sys/class/backlight/`

output : `intel_backlight`

edit 1:

This question is not a duplicate of "[Why don't my Fn keys work for brightness or media after upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89386/why-dont-my-fn-keys-work-for-brightness-or-media-after-upgrading)"  ,since my keys are mapped to the correct buttons. The problem did not occur after the a distro upgrade and the also, the solution suggested did not work.

command :     `acpi_listen`

output :

```
video/brightnessdown BRTDN 00000087 00000000
video/brightnessup BRTUP 00000086 00000000
```

Comment: Please edit your question, what do you mean by "Also I have disabled GPU-manager ***since resulted in slow booting after changing to systemd***."?

Comment: I  have remove the line since I realized it is ambiguous.  I have disabled gpu-manager.service to run at boot, which is related to Graphics card(and possibly brightness) .Re-enabling the service doesn't help either

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't my Fn keys work for brightness or media after upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89386/why-dont-my-fn-keys-work-for-brightness-or-media-after-upgrading)